# Setting browser homepage through JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to forcibly set a page as a homepage on the user's browser without any user notification or confirmation?

Comment: Is there any way to forcible remove this question, without the user notification or confirmation? :P Seriously though there is no way (thank god) unless through an exploit or something, and there shouldn't be. This would cause absolute online chaos.

Comment: Tell the admins on the user's network to do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No.** You cannot do this, and should not be able to do this as it is unethical to change a user's preferences without notifying him or her.

Here is a good example of how to do it with notification, however:
http://javascript.internet.com/page-details/set-homepage-link.html

There's also the chance that you're interested in doing this for legitimate reasons, i.e. a corporate deployment script or some such. You can look into ways of doing it across an entire Active Directory using Group Policies and deployment scripts.

Comment: Glad to see someone use "unethical" explicitly.

Answer (score 4):

No, there isn't, and thank God for that.

Seriously, have you thought through the consequences? Every web site could set their users' home pages to their hearts' content.

Answer (score 3):

Even if it's possible, I doubt many SO users are going to rush to tell you how.  This is extremely intrusive and abusive behavior.

If I knew how, I wouldn't tell you.  This is something that just should not be done.